# How can I give a disabled `lightning-input` a background color?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightninginput

I have successfully given enabled `lightning-input` fields in my app background colors using `--slds-c-input-color-background`, but this seems to be ignored (removed) from the final page rendering. How can I give a disabled `lightning-input` field a background other than the light grey one it has by default?

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I tried `--slds-c-input-color-background-disabled` but that didn't work.

Comment: @usernameabc, I did not. The project was under time pressure, so we ignored the feature for now. The only solution I was able to come close to is to use just the field's value instead of placing it in an LWC `lightning-input`.

Comment: Before Salesforce release the UI update that improve accessibility for low vision users, this css hook `--lwc-colorBackgroundInputDisabled` works just fine. After that, it doesn't work anymore.